# What causes a VW Golf 2017 engine warning light to appear?

Tags: engine, vw, warning-light

I did a test drive of a used VW Golf 2017 manual transmission, 140 000 km. The yellow engine warning light appears when the key is half-turned and disappears when the engine starts. What could cause it to appear and is it worth checking?

Answer (score 3):

That's completely normal behavior. It's just testing the light.

Comes in very handy when you're looking at a used car. If you don't see the light, the owner may have blocked it or disconnected it - and that's shady.

Answer (score 2):

You did a test drive of the car and the car did a test (drive) of the light.

If it stays out while engine is running then all should be ok.

Most cars will test all the gauges and lights as the ignition is switched on then as long as they go out when the engine is running all is normal.

These lights are called warning lights as they come on when, and if, there is an issue. The obvious one is for the parking or handbrake - it stays illuminated until you release it.